# How to push my code to a new branch which does not exist in the remote repo

Tags: git

I cloned a repository from the gitserver master. I have done some changes in the local and need to get some debug from others in my team. So I would like to push it to a new branch, which does not exist yet in the remote repo. I would like my local git to create a branch in the gitserver and be able to push it. How would I be able to accomplish it?

ps: I am in the head of local. I do not want to create a branch in the local

Answer (score 5):

Commit your changes, and then this will take the local master branch and push it to a remote branch without creating a new local branch.

```
git push origin master:remote-branch-name
```

If you want to reset your master branch after pushing those commits to the remote branch you can do

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a new branch with `git checkout -b <branch_name>`, and push it with `git push -u origin <branch_name>`.

Then, everyone can see your branch, and if you need to make changes to it, it's as straightforward as changing to the branch, committing, and pushing it up.

Comment: Yes, but that's not a very good idea.  You'd have to jump through more hoops to get back to the branch if you wanted to do a quick update to it than you would if you just created a local branch yourself.  They're cheap; if you *really* don't want it, you can always delete it.